# Matcher find nothing in a text similar to regexp pattern

Tags: java, regex

Every time I need to work with regexps I run at similar problems. They just don't work for me, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I have a text line:

> insert into base (db) arg (*any possible int*);

Such lines may also contain comment at the end. What I need is to find such lines. Here is how I try to do it:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String UPDATE_REGEXP = "insert into base (db) arg (\\d*+)";
    String sample = "insert into base (db) arg (100);";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(UPDATE_REGEXP);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    } else {
        fail();
    }
}
```

I also tried the simpliest regexp ever:

> String UPDATE_REGEXP = "insert into base (db) arg";

But this test always fails. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape parenthesis since they are [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in RegEx (they are used to create [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) for instance). Try

```
String UPDATE_REGEXP = "insert into base \\(db\\) arg \\(\\d*+\\)";
```

Comment: Oh. It appeared to be so simple. Thanks. I have to read metacharacters-basics more attentively.

Comment: @Dragon No problem, you can find link to list of special characters in my updated answer.